# Error installing MAP-REDUCE plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, plugins

When I'm trying to install MAP-REDUCE plug-in in eclipse INDIGO I am getting following kind of error

Screenshot: [image]

I have install hadoop 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you are trying to use was compiled using Java 8 but you are running Eclipse using an earlier version of Java.

You will have to run your Eclipse using Java 8 to use this plugin.